# How to call method/function in where clause of a LINQ query as IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, linq

I have the problem to use function inside the `where` clause in linq query as seen in the code below.

1. Function which return `IEnumerable` object:

   ```
   private IEnumerable filterparameter(string filter) 
   {        
       EmailAflAwmMessageDM obj = new EmailAflAwmMessageDM();

       if (filter == "attachments")
       {
           return obj.attachments;
       }
       else if (filter == "flagged")
       {
           return obj.flagged;
       }
       else
       {
           return obj.seen;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Function which returns `IQuerable`, which will be used in web api function:

   ```
   private IQueryable SearchFilterCondition(string filter,string value)
   {
       var emailmessage = from a in db.EmailAflAwmMessage
                          where (filterparameter(filter) == value)
                          orderby a.msg_date descending
                          select new
                          {
                              a.subject,
                              a.msg_date,         
                          };
       return emailmessage;
   }
   ```

**update: this error**

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace":null,
"InnerException": {
    "Message":"An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage":"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.IEnumerable filterparameter(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.",
    "ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException",
    "StackTrace":"
```

Please help me to resolve this problem or guide me with an alternate.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Do you get an error? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: You need to run something like `var x = filterparameter(filter).First(f => f == value)`, then use `where x == value` in your linq expression.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i have the following erorr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Domysee Mentioned you cannot call any c# function within a Linq query. Only [EntitiFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
That's why expressions have been built for. To be used inside linq queries

```
        public Expression<Func<EmailAflAwmMessage, bool>> GetSelectXpr(string filter, string value)
        {
            if (filter == "attachments")
                return e => e.attachments == value;
            else if (filter == "flagged")
                return e => e.flagged == value;
            else
                return e => e.seen == value;
        }
```

Usage.

```
var selectXpr = GetGetSelectXpr(filter,value);
    var emailmessage = db.EmailAflAwmMessage.Where(selectXpr).OrderByDescending(a=>a.msg_date).Select(a=> 
     new {
     a.subject,
     a.msg_date
   })
```

Comment: thanks for your time, its give me error when i applied this way in linq where clause "operator can not be used operand as bool", can you please check it again. thanks

Comment: i have still error to use in where clause, the name selecXpr does not exists in the current context. thanks for your time, please any alternate.

Comment: If you just copied and pasted my code, i have a typo in the variable name. Make sure you use the same name

Comment: thanks for your help and your valuable time. now its working with lambda expression, can we use it with linq expression. thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to use methods inside a `Where` of an `IQueryable`, because Linq to SQL cannot know how to translate your method into SQL.

You have to inline your method into the `Where` to make it work.
Something like that:

```
private IQueryable SearchFilterCondition(string filter,string value)
{
    var filterParam = filterparameter(filter); //evaluate filterparameter outside of the query
    var emailmessage = from a in db.EmailAflAwmMessage
                       where (filterParam == value)
                       orderby a.msg_date descending
                       select new
                       {
                           a.subject,
                           a.msg_date,         
                       };
    return emailmessage;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. when i applied the above code, it works with no error but does n't return any record. can you check it please. thanks for your time.

Comment: @adnan I believe this is because the two objects are never the same. Try using `filterParam.SequenceEqual(value)` in the where clause

Comment: filterParam.SequenceEqual(value) this is not applicable in linq, but i test it with filterParam.Equals(value) but also still no record get. thanks for your time.

Comment: @adnan maybe you can try iterating through all elements in a lambda expression and check if each one is in filterparam (so essentailly implementing SequenceEquals yourself). Sorry I cant be of more help, but I'm not at home right now and dont have a test project available.